# Setting up a web developer lab for learning purposes

Tags: testing, environment, simulate

I'm not a developer by profession. Therefore, I'm not exposed to real world technical problems that face professional developers. I read/heard about web farms, integration between different systems, load balancing ... etc.

Therefore, I was wondering if there are ways for the individual developer to create an environment that simulates real world situations with minimal number of machines like:

- web farms & caching
- simulating many users accessing your website (Pressure tests?)
- Performance
- load balancing
- anything you think I should consider.

By the way, I have a server machine and 1 PC. and I don't mind investing in tools and software.
PS. I'm using Microsoft technologies for development but I hope this is not a limiting factor.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I am new, SO will not let me post more than one link, so I compiled a list of links for you at a pastebin [here](http://pastedown.lunant.net/7015b7).

Comment: Thanks for the links. I thought nobody will ever answer this question. I have a question of why you recommend the following links (not that I mind but I'm curious especially you have about 13 years of experience):                                              - [Learn Python The Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/index)
- [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html)

Comment: @Saleh, SICP will give you a good understanding of basic CS theory, and LPTHW will give you a good understanding of commonly experienced scenarios in web development.

Comment: @BrendonCrawford The pastebin link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

alot of tools for this. i like
http://www.acme.com/software/http_load/
and http://curl-loader.sourceforge.net/

they both can simulaty much queries to your server. Run it from another machine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It only answer one part of my question. Maybe others will answer the remaining ones. Thanks again.